# Symbolic links are not accessible from IIS FTP

Tags: iis, windows-10

I want to share files and folders kept in NAS drive through IIS FTP server.
User is able to see all files including my symbolic link of folder which is on NAS drive but when user try to access he/she gets error "username or password incorrect".

How do I make NAS drive files available through my IIS FTP server.

Comment: Is your issue solved? If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue. If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members. If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it. We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have assigned the iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the shared folder. check FTP authentication basic is disabled and anonymous is enabled:

[image]

add authorization allow rule for the user:

[image]

at the time of connection enter the username: testdomain/administrator and password correctly.